# Enabling rtl support in Vuetify implemented through CDN

Tags: vuetify.js, right-to-left

I am using vuetify through CDN. I need rtl support for my application. How can I enable rtl when using CDN. The following didnot work for me:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  rtl: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve it by putting rtl= true inside created event as following:

```
new Vue({
    data(){ return {
      // data
       }
    },
    created () {
       this.$vuetify.rtl = true;
    }

})
```

The same could be done for each components as well.